# Override orders page with a panel page

Tags: panels

How can I create a panels page for path admin/commerce/orders/*

I've set a existing page override
[image: Existing page override]

And created the panel with selection rules.
[image: panel]

It still doesnt work. Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Deactivate** the view with the same URL so there is no collision. Clear the cache and it should work.

Comment: I Cleared the cache it says "admin/commerce/orders/* has not been overridden because the menu item does not exist. The view comes from the "line items view" witch has a contextual filter and no path.

Comment: @sas sometimes you need to swap places for substitution to work, with modules weights or for certain hooks. It's a weak point of Drupal, sadly.

Comment: I ended up creating another page on a different url for the orders. A little easier for me than to create hooks.