# What does "path has not been overridden because the menu item does not exist." mean

Tags: routes

I've noticed the following error message in a few different situations.

> Path has not been overridden because the menu item does not exist.

Cases in witch I have seen the error message

- Trying to override admin/commerce/orders/% with a panel.
- Also using "Views PDF Display" + "rules link" to send a pdf to a user's email.

The downside I see so far for this message is that I cant override the url with a panel.

I Think it is because a module has already taken control of that path.

Is there a way to see what is causing the error message?

Comment: I think it is happening due to the reason of path creation, which you have mentioned in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83350/how-to-create-a-multiple-argument-panel-path

Comment: Does this error message basically mean that the path has already been overridden some where else? I got the same message with a "views pdf" display.

Comment: No. It means this path doesn't exists. System is not able to find this menu path..

Comment: Note that it actually relates to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83178/ . It would be nice if a more detailed description for this error message could be added for more of a beginners perceptive based on the hooks and module weights comment.

Comment: When you got solution, post that here too. Good luck :)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The question should provide more details. When exactly do you get that error? What are you doing when you get that error message? Are you changing the settings a third-party module is using, or changing the setting for a Drupal core module? Please edit the question; don't answer in a comment.